# Using Three20 with an another protocol than HTTP

Tags: iphone, three20

I'm just starting to discover Three20, and would like to know in which direction to look for using Three20 with another protocol than HTTP. Three20 uses requests by URLs, and I would like to request files (for examples photos in TTImageView) using a different protocol (a home made one).

If you can just tell me if it's possible without hacking too much into Three20, that'll be nice

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL requests are fairly solidly baked in to the library, and they assume a connection over HTTP (though it doesn't technically have to be HTTP). I don't know of an easy inflection point for implementing your own protocol, though - I would mark this as significant work.